# Insertar imágenes en Excel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

les platico rápidamente mi consulta.
Estoy modificando un sistema web escrito en Visual Basic con ASP.net. Entonces, hay una parte donde se llena un `GridView` jalando datos de una base de datos de Access después se genera en Excel:

```
Protected Sub btnExportarExcel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExportarExcel.Click
    Call Exportar_Excel(grdDatos)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Exportar_Excel(ByVal pGrid As GridView)
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter(sb)
    Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim pagina As System.Web.UI.Page = New System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim form = New HtmlForm
    Dim lnAlto As Integer

    pGrid.AllowPaging = False
    pGrid.BottomPagerRow.Visible = False

    pGrid.EnableViewState = False
    pagina.EnableEventValidation = False
    pagina.DesignerInitialize()
    pagina.Controls.Add(form)
    form.Controls.Add(pGrid)
    'form.Controls.Add(grdMeEscuelasDet)
    pagina.RenderControl(htw)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    'Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Resumen_Anual" & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & ".xls")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Resumen_Anual" & ".xls")
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"

    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default
    Response.Write(sb.ToString())
    Response.End()

    pGrid.Columns(0).Visible = True
End Sub

Protected Sub List_Conceptos_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles List_Conceptos.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Protected Sub grdDatos_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdDatos.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo el siguiente paso es agregar una imagen en la cabecera del documento que se genera en excel pero sin modificar el `Gridview` que se muestra en la página web.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes que alterar el excel no vas a poder usar esa tecnica de exportacion mediante el render de html.

Vas a tener que usa alguna libreria que permita generar el documento, recomendaria evalues librerias basadas en `open xml`

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

[SpreadSheetLigth](http://spreadsheetlight.com/)

si tienes los datos en un datatable podrias exportarlo facilmente,
analiza la seccion

[Inserting Data/Tables](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation)

con estas librerias al tener el archivo en memoria podrias agregarle la imagen y luego enviarlo en el Response

Comment: Gracias, Leandro pero checando los links que me diste, veo que una de las bibliotecas es para C# y yo estoy manejando VB, ¿debería probar otra forma de exportación a Excel?

Comment: si los ejemplos estan en c# pero es lo mismo, puedes usar la libreria sin problemas ya que todo es .net. A donde apunto es que no uses las api de office

Comment: Bien, veré entonces qué tal me va. Mil gracias.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini y se puede subir una foto almacenada en sql server y exportar en un excel ?